# The Service class in MVC

Tags: php, object-oriented, mvc

From time to time I find there is a need to build a service class. Something I can't really attach inside a model in order to respected GRASP and SOLID.

So I created a class called AccountTransferService.

Are service classes good design practice ?

Do they represent a Model ?

If a Service is not a Model what are they in a MVC arhitecture ?

Comment: Everything that is *business logic* is *the model*. The Model in MVC may well contain several different things, including business objects and "services".

Comment: Martin Fowler calls it [Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are service classes good design practice ?

As long as they do not contain business logic or state but only orchestrate other components, yes. For additional information, see http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html

> Do they represent a Model ?

The Model in MVC is your application minus the User Interface (V+C). As such, a Service is part of *the* Model, but it is not *a* Model in the sense of a Domain Model. They are also not what frameworks like Code Igniter usually (and incorrectly) mean when they talk about models.

> If a Service is not a Model what are they in a MVC arhitecture ?

See above, they part of *the* Model

Comment: If my /models folder contains a lot of ORM generated classes, would It be a good idea to place the services in a separate folder /models/services or is there another practice for this ?

Comment: @danip Where to put stuff in the filesystem is ultimately up to you or your coding convention. For instance, if you follow PSR-2 you will have a close match between class names and folders.

Comment: @Gordon - but Models by definition contain business logic and Services are Models.

Comment: @danip Services are part of the Model (Layer). That layer contains Domain *Models*, which contain your business logic. Services usually dont contain any business logic of their own, but only orchestrate other components. But I am repeating myself :)

Comment: @Gordon - I know about the Fowler's Service Layer but is there any reference about the Model Layer? I found a bit confusing the term "Model" at this point. Also the "Service Layer" seems to be a concept from Domain Driven Development. Could you make a clear distinction between a pure MVC application with Services and a MVC&DDD application? What would be the layers and components in both cases?

Comment: @danip You can find a good write-up about Domain Models in Fowler's, Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture (pg 116) and also in the chapter about MVC (pg 330). Summaries can be found at http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html.